# What is the best way to sprout Lychee seeds?

Tags: germination, lychee

I am attempting to sprout some lychee pits using the moist paper towel in a ziplock method. So far it has resulted in mold on the towel and tops of the seeds. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information overload!

Sometimes it does not matter if a seed grown fruit tree bears fruit, sometimes it's just nice to experience with new seeds or enjoy the foliage of plants nurseries usual do not carry.

The steps:
-Remove/brush all pulp from seeds - pulp=mold
-Wash the seeds with warm water, add a few drops of dish liquid
-Rinse seeds well
-Wrap seed in a clean paper towel or coffee filter
-Moisten with distilled water, rain water will do also, 
(adding a few drops of H2O2/Hyrdogen peroxide assists with fungus control, but it's not a requirement)
-Keep at 70-75F in a zip lock bag.
-Change the dressing every other day, moisten
-Keep damp but not wet - too much water=rot 
-Germination in 2-6 weeks

Good luck!

Comment: Out of 7 seeds 4 have definitely broken through their shell despite my non-ideal set up. I planted them yesterday and we will see if they turn into trees. Thanks for the steps. I will definitely use these next time I try to sprout. (I'm pretty sure my seeds sprouted within a week of retrieving them from the fruit)

Comment: I've tried the same method in the fridge. Nothing happening after about 2 weeks time (I've read that a few days was sufficient). No mold on mine though. I'll keep waiting!

Answer (score 5):

I'm no expert on Lychee, but mold is usually a bad thing and indicates too much moisture or not enough fresh air getting to your germinating medium.

[This](http://hortsci.ashspublications.org/content/31/7/1187.full.pdf) paper has some results on Lychee seed germination that you might be interested in.

Answer (score 2):

I did mine in moist paper towels. I didn't put in a ziploc bag. I put mine in a plastic container with lid. I checked them daily for moisture. It sounds like the ziploc bag isn't the way to go. They do need air also. I've done a total of 25 Lychee seeds with moist paper towels and never had a mold problem. They were done at different intervals of course. Did you soak them in water for 3 days changing the water daily? I now have my first 2 I did sprouting up out of the soil. Good luck an I hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Lychee doesn’t grow true to seed kinda like apple slices. You need to start the tree with a branch from the mother. If you want the same fruit and taste. If you’re growing it from seed skip paper towels start it right in a pot. Should sprout in a week or three. If it takes more than a month it’s bad. Try to plant the seed within a week of taking it from the fruit.  And in about 10-25 years you’ll have some fruit.

Edit: if you bought just the seeds don’t worry about the mother plant.

Answer (score 0):

I have sprouted the seeds with ease. Soak them in warm water for 3 days, then put them in a paper towel, spray it with water for moisture and then into a ziplock bag. This works 100%. Once you see the roots, transplant them into soil.