# Can I plant the Lychee plant from the Fruit Seed ?

Tags: fruit-trees, lychee

I am not a pro at gardening or farming, and some people do tell me not to plant seeds from the fruit, and rather buy them and plant them.

But what do you guys think about planting Lychee Fruit seeds directly ? 
Is it fine to just remove the pulp(from the fruit) , Wash - Dry and Plant the seed directly ? 
Or should I buy the seeds from the market and plant them ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends on what are looking to get out of it. If you are looking for fruit, the results are a bit unpredictable as Lychee (and for that matter most fruit trees) do not breed true. A plant grown from the seed of a very good fruit can produce fruit that isn't nearly as good. For production purposes, lychee are mainly propagated by air-layering. If you're interested in getting quality fruit I'd suggest just buying a plant.

If you're looking to grow the plant for the interest of having one I would suggest reviewing the answer to [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/11143/what-is-the-best-way-to-sprout-lychee-seeds). Lychee seeds will dry out and lose viability in the space of a few days once removed from the fruit unless you start the germination process.

Comment: Thanks, it is for the fruit(for the produce) tree that I am looking to grow .

Comment: Then you'd be best off buying a named variety of lychee as a plant, then you know what you're going to get - but this is one plant where you will get better fruiting if you plant two different varieties which flower at the same time, for cross pollination.